# Maximum Number of Solutions from Derivative

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I have a general question. Suppose I have the graph of a derivative of a function $g(x)$. How can I go about finding the maximum number of solutions where $g(x) = 0$?

My understanding is that there can be a maximum of two solutions since there is at most one solution on $[a,0]$ where $g$ is decreasing, and at most one solution on $[0,b]$ where $g$ is increasing. However, I am not sure if I am correctly applying the monotonicity of intervals.

[image: I have attached the graph of derivative.]

Comment: You need to give more information about the problem.

Comment: I am not looking for the exact answer. I just want to know the maximum number of solutions possible in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argument is correct. Under those assumptions, the number of solutions is $0$, $1$ or $2$, but never more than $2$.